# Need help on Array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I don't understand some parts in the following code:

```
    For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
        txt = Join$(Array(a(i, 3), a(i, 4)), Chr(2))
        If Not dic.exists(txt) Then
            Set dic(txt) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        dic(txt)(a(i, 1)) = VBA.Array(a(i, 5), a(i, 6), a(i, 2))
        
    Next
```

- Q1: Why set dic(txt) in the loop code
- Q2: dic(txt)(a(i,1)) => Why they use (a(i,1))

Thanks alot

Comment: It is looping through an array `a` with a counter of `i`, it is joining `a(i,3)` and `a(i,4)` and if the result of this join `txt` does not `exist` in the `dictionary` `dic` it creates an entry for `txt` as the key in the `dic`  then it sets this new or existing entry `txt` by `dic(txt)` with the item of `a(i,1)` to be the array created using `vba.array`  I think (it's friday afternoon) need a beer :-)  I think it's getting the last value of `a(i, 5), a(i, 6), a(i, 2)` and making it accessible in a dictionary via the key `a(i, 3), a(i, 4))`

Comment: Thanks Nathan, why does he Set dic(txt) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") in the loop. Normally, i add CreateObject before the loop code

Comment: It is, the dictionary dic is created outside, but the dictionary within dic, is created when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

### Dictionary of Dictionaries

- Loop through the elements of the 1st dimension (rows) of a multi-dimensional array (`a`):

  ```
  For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
  ```
- Revealing that `a` is a 2D array, joining the elements of columns 3 and 4 into a string (`txt`).

  ```
  txt = Join$(Array(a(i, 3), a(i, 4)), Chr(2))
  ```

  or to simplify:

  ```
  txt = a(i, 3) & Chr(2) & a(i, 4)
  ```
- Checking if `txt` exists as a *key* in the existing dictionary (`dic`).

  ```
  If Not dic.exists(txt) Then
  End If
  ```
- If it doesn't, add a new dictionary as an *item* associated with the current *key*:

  ```
  Set dic(txt) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  ```

  1. *Key* is `txt`,
  2. *Item* is a new (inner) dictionary.
- Use the value in the first column of the array (`a`) as the *key* in the new dictionary and add a zero-based (`VBA.` ensures zero-based) array with the values from columns 5, 6, and 2 of array `a` as the associated *item* to the new dictionary (of course only if the 1st column value does not already exist in the 'new' (inner) dictionary):

  ```
  dic(txt)(a(i, 1)) = VBA.Array(a(i, 5), a(i, 6), a(i, 2))
  ```
- dic:

  - *Key* is `txt`
  - *Item* is new (inner) dic:

    - *Key* is `a(i, 1)`
    - *Item* is `VBA.Array(...)`

Comment: Thanks VBasic2008, i need time to understand your instruction.